# In JavaScript, how do I parse a Date that is always day followed by the month followed by the year?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to parse the `Date` from a `string`, however every time I parse it I have to specify the format the string is in, but my string can either be `dd-MM-yy` or  `d/m/yyyy` or `d-MM-yyyy,` its always changing, so writing out all the different formats will be challenging, is there a way to parse it if I know the string will always be the day followed by the month followed by the year? Either with JavaScripts date constructor or a third party library like Moment.js

Comment: if you are just starting a project don't use moment [see project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this example code

```
const dateString = "05-05-2023"; // example date string in "day-month-year" format

const parts = dateString.split(/[-\/]/); // split the string into parts using either "-" or "/" as the delimiter

const year = parts[2];
const month = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1; // subtract 1 from the month because it is zero-indexed in the Date() constructor
const day = parts[0];

const date = new Date(year, month, day);

console.log(date); // Fri May 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code, I didnt exactly get it but while I was using moment.js
and I had date of any kind , we can format is by using

```
moment(your_date).format('D-MM-YYYY') or  moment(your_date).format('D/MM/YYYY');
```

If that clears your doubt then well and good otherwise let me know what have you sent and what exactly is required in code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply match for numbers (i.e. days, month, year), then use the [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date):

```js
function parseDate(dateString) {
  const [days, month, year] = dateString.match(/\d+/g);
  const monthIndex = month - 1;

  return new Date(year, monthIndex, days);
}

console.log(parseDate("2-5-23"));
console.log(parseDate("02-05-2023"));
console.log(parseDate("02/05/2023"));
```